# ReportViewer (.rdlc) light designer for WinForms

Tags: winforms, reporting-services, reporting, reportviewer

Are there any other ReportViewer designer beside the Visual Studio (with GUI of course I know that any XML/TEXT editor can change definition of .rdlc file) ?
One day when I finish my rich (fat) client application at all, Ill love to try embed in report designer, so end users can do cosmetics modification of theirs report files without having installed Visual Studio.
Sub question, does this feature have CrystalReport service ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I tried an opensource editor: http://www.fyireporting.com/products.html, and it works! (I have several WinForms apps which use the ReportViewer from Visual Studio 2008). You can, of course, download the sources also and adapt it if needed.

Comment: As far as I reading FAQ this look great, Does this project still live and does this is going to last.

Comment: Now you can use a fork of fyiReporting: https://github.com/majorsilence/My-FyiReporting

Answer (score 0):

Visual Studio Community is Free and includes all the functionality of Visual Studio Professional.

http://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/products/visual-studio-community-vs.aspx